# Threads getting blocked JAXB

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, jaxb

even after creating new object of unmarshaller every time, threads are getting blocked 
Please help

```
"http-80-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004fabe800 nid=0x7147 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000042401000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:457)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000c02cce20> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:475)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:371)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.tailor(ClassTailor.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.tailor(AccessorInjector.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:245)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
```

Comment: public static <T> T unmarshal(Class<? extends T> type, InputStream in) {
          try {
              JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            Unmarshaller unMarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
            return unMarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(in), type).getValue();
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            LOGGER.warn("Could not un marshal type: " + type, ex);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The type: " +     type.getName() + " could not be unmarshalled", ex);
          }
      }

Comment: Are you creating a `JAXBContext` every time?  `JAXBContext` is thread safe and should be created once and reused.  An `Unmarshaller` is not thread safe an a new one should be created per thread.

Comment: Thanks Blaise Doughan, I did exactly as you mentioned, the problem was  we were creating one JAXBContext for every type and in our system we have many such objects. Now I am maintaining a map (ConcurrentHashMap<Class, JAXBContext> contexts ) wrapped by thread safe code to store all JAXBContexts(one per type) as of now it is working nicely. Any other better suggestion ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Moving my comment to an answer)

Are you creating a JAXBContext every time? JAXBContext is thread safe and should be created once and reused. An Unmarshaller is not thread safe an a new one should be created per thread.

> Now I am maintaining a map (ConcurrentHashMap
>   contexts ) wrapped by thread safe code to store all JAXBContexts(one
>   per type) as of now it is working nicely. Any other better suggestion
>   ??

It depends on your application.  You can also create one `JAXBContext` on many classes:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class);
```

or

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.foo:org.bar");
```

Comment: Old thread so don't know if you'll see this Blaise but is there any significant performance improvements to be achieved through creating a JAXBContext instance per marshable class or creating one JAXBContext for multiple marshable classes.

Comment: @CodeClimber - There is provider look up mechanism that occurs whenever a `JAXBContext` creation occurs.  Performance wise it would be better to create 1 context on N classes rather than N contexts each on 1 class.

Comment: Thanks. P.S. is "marshable" a word? Or "marshalable"?

Comment: @CodeClimber I'm not sure if either is a word, but I would say "marshalable" :).

Answer (score 1):

a good solution to performance troublesooting reliable to JAXB Context when developping multithreaded web apps can be creation of singleton which provide JAXBContext like this :

```
class JAXBContextServletHelper  extends HttpServlet {
    static final JAXBContext context = initContext();
    private static JAXBContext initContext() {
        return JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClasse1.class,MyClasse2.class);
    }
}
```

and call it using ;

```
JAXBContext context =   JAXBContextServletHelper. initContext();
Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
        u.unmarshal(...);
```

for more details on this question please visit the jaxb tutorial on java.net [here](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html)