# Java thread dump, can't find thread that blocking others

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-dump, jstack

Our application is lagging.

I'm get thread dump using `jstack` util.

I do a data preparation and sort it. And this is what I have:

```
198    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)

198    - waiting to lock <0x0000000582e56bc8> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector)
```

198 threads are BLOCKED.

As I understand from `waiting to lock <0x0000000582e56bc8>`, they all waiting some thread with ID `0x0000000582e56bc8`. The strange thing is that I cannot find this `0x0000000582e56bc8` in thread dump output, I cannot find what they all waiting for.

Or it is not true? What is this `0x0000000582e56bc8`?

Here is little peace of dump:

```
"http-thread-pool-8080(790)" daemon prio=3 tid=0x00000001100fa000 nid=0x339a waiting for monitor entry [0xfffffffeec1f6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:82)
        - waiting to lock <0x0000000582e56bc8> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector)
```

All 198 other thread dumps are the same

*Update 1. After @Holder comment*

```
"http-thread-pool-8080(642)" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000110a8c800 nid=0x32ec runnable [0xffffffff05af5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:256)
        - locked <0x000000058f2af0c0> (a java.util.zip.ZStreamRef)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory$WeakZipFile$WeakZipInputStream.read(WeakZipFileFactory.java:669)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:312)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.tailor(ClassTailor.java:173)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.tailor(AccessorInjector.java:126)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:85)
        - locked <0x0000000582e56bc8> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:176)
```

**Update 2** Thanks for @Holder

As I understand `waiting to lock <0x0000000582e56bc8>`, means that thread is waiting for `0x0000000582e56bc8`, which is a pointer. Next you should find `- locked <0x0000000582e56bc8>`. And you will find Thread that locked an object. Then I looked at stack trace and finally, find the culprit.

If you have also problem with `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector`, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203893/threads-getting-blocked-jaxb).

Comment: `0x0000000582e56bc8` is an object not a thread.

Comment: As Dhrubajyoti Gogoi has pointed out, `0x0000000582e56bc8` is an object. Now watch out for a `- locked <0x0000000582e56bc8>` entry in the stack traces to find out which thread has the lock on that object.

Comment: @Holger. I found only one entry. Updated question. This means that Thread with `tid=0x0000000110a8c800 nid=0x32ec` locking all other Thread?

Comment: @c0rp It seems very much as if.

Comment: Yes, and as you might notice, the thread owning the lock acquired that lock at the very same method where the other threads are waiting for that lock. In other words, it looks like `AccessorInjector.prepare(…)` is a `static synchronized` method. And that’s the point of `synchronized`, only one thread can proceed, all others have to wait.

Comment: Well, instead of being `static synchronized`, `AccessorInjector.prepare(…)` might contain a `synchronized (AccessorInjector.class)` statement; the result would be the same…

Comment: @Holger It would be nice if you write an answer, may be it will help someone else. Any way Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize how to read the stack traces to find the problem as done in the question’s comments:

If you find an entry like

```
  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:82)
  - waiting to lock <0x0000000582e56bc8> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector)
```

within your stack trace you know that the thread is trying to lock an object instance which is represented by the number `0x0000000582e56bc8` and the text in the braces tell you further that this object is the `Class` instance representing the runtime class `AccessorInjector`.

Since this class object represent the class that is declaring the method it is possible that the method is a `static synchronized` method but it is also possible that the method contains a construct like `synchronized(AccessorInjector.class)`.

So you have to find a thread whose stack trace contains a matching `- locked` entry to learn which threads blocks the others.

Since you found the match as

```
  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:85)
  - locked <0x0000000582e56bc8> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector)
```

we see that the thread which has locked the object is executing the same method as the waiting threads so everything turn out to be plausible if this method is `synchronized` or contains a `synchronized(AccessorInjector.class)` block.

It’s the invariant property of Java’s intrinsic locks that only one thread can proceed with having the object locked while an arbitrary number of other threads must wait.